# Drawing a unfilled square in C#.net on top of a stream video?

Tags: c#, directshow

Does anyone know with what I can draw a unfilled square on a live video stream/saved video in C#.net?

Someone said to use Directshow but it is for C++ users. Is there a feature in dshownet that addresses this issue ?

Another said to use XNA, but my project is a object tracking application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation sounds like it's addressed by the DxLogo sample @ http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html

> DxLogo – A sample application showing how to superimpose a logo on a data stream. It uses a capture device for the video source, and outputs the result to a file.

Just replace the logo with an unfilled square :)